# Do the underlying page properties matter when includegraphics reads PDF or converted EPS/PS vector graphics?

Tags: graphics, pdf, eps, epstopdf

This is perhaps a beginner/simple question, but how does includegraphics determine the "box" encapsulating a vector graphic embedded on, say, a letter-size paper?

When I read my EPS files (generated with Matlab) using GhostView, they appear in some corner of a full-size, otherwise blank page. Do the various page properties (like orientation, type, etc.) matter? And *why* does there need to be some blank page underneath the saved graphic for that matter? I'm trying to understand how best to prepare figures for publication.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `\includegraphics` reads the bounding box of the .eps  file. It may happen this bounding box is wrong. To check this point, write `\fbox{\includegraphics{foo.eps}}`. There exist tools to crop `eps`files (`epspdf`, for instance, can do it).

Comment: Your question looks like an [XY problem](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2449/5763) and as such is a bit difficult to answer. Please clarify your actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

For PDF the engines and device drivers read the `MediaBox`, i.e. the dimensions of the included page. The `Orientation` is also used.